# Connect to DUN using bluetooth in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bluetooth

[image]Whenever i try to access DUN using Bluetooth GUI i always get Connection Timeout, that didn't happened before when i was using 12.04.

Can anyone tell, is there any specific bluetooth issue in 14.04.?

Further i would like to get some command line steps to use my phone's bluetooth as internet source for my ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: What is the result from `lsusb` and `uname -r` in terminal.  Some bluetooth devices now need firmware because of some changes

Comment: lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:6473 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


and uname -r

3.13.0-46-generic

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the firmware you need

`wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ryy3ir1tby6wrf/fw-0a5c_21d7.hcd`

`sudo cp fw-0a5c_21d7.hcd /lib/firmware`

`sudo cp fw-0a5c_21d7.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm`

Then you can see if it worked

`sudo modprobe -r btusb`

`sudo modprobe btusb`

Then `dmesg | grep -i firmware` -post this info and see if DUN will work

Comment: i got this [    0.131304] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[   18.754714] Bluetooth: firmware loaded


and still i am getting error : "timed out detecting phone details"

Comment: Are you using Blueman or just the default bluetooth manager in Ubuntu?  I have no issues refreshing services from my phone but it must not support DUN but I can tether to it using bluetooth

Comment: I am using default bluetooth manager. And i have also tried restarting the btusb as well as the system. But still i am getting the same error when tether using bluetooth. Again i must mention, earlier with 12.04, it worked pretty well.

Comment: 12.04 might be the only fix but it might be a good idea to file a bug report https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs